# shell script to erase backups on ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu, erase

I have this little script which is supposed to erase backups older then one month which are stored in a folder. But it doesn't work.
Files are sql.gz
File name example: CUSTOMER_2015-01-12-09:05.sql.gz

```
NOW=$(date --date '1 month ago' + '*%Y-%m*.sql.gz')
rm -rf /home/path/CUSTOMER_$NOW
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a extra space after `+` that is why it is not working

```
NOW=$(date --date '1 month ago' +'*%Y-%m*.sql.gz')
rm -rf /home/path/CUSTOMER_$NOW
```

Comment: add `echo $NOW` and see what is being printed. Also do a `echo rm -riv /home/path/CUSTOMER_$NOW` and use the command manually to check what you are getting

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. He does remove the content from June but not before. When I echo $NOW he responds *2017-06*.sql.gz
Well the space was it then. Thanks